# Swipe JS not working with populated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I'm using Swipe JS 2.
If I make the HTML structure myself, it works perfectly, but if I populate the HTML with content coming from the jQuery, it stops on the second slide.

My HTML structure:

```
<div id="map" class="swipe">
    <div class="swipe-wrap">
        <div class="city" id="current">
            <div class="location">Current Location</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul id="position">
        <li class="on">Current location</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my structure on the jQuery.

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/locations.php", function(localdata) {
    $.each(localdata.locations, function(i, geolocal){
        var vcountry = geolocal['country'];
        var vregion = geolocal['region'];
        var vcity = geolocal['city'];

        country = vcountry.replace(' ','_');
        region = vregion.replace(' ','_');
        city = vcity.replace(' ','_');

        // THE PROBLEM IS HERE. IF I USE AJAX OR GETJSON HERE INSIDE THE OTHER GETJSON, THE SWIPE IS BROKEN.
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost/remotexml.php?url=http://www.yr.no/place/"+ country +"/"+ region +"/"+ city +"/forecast.xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                var localName = $(xml).find('location name').text();
                $('#map div.swipe-wrap .city:last-child').after('\n<div class="city">\n<div class="location">'+localName+'</div>\n</div>\n</div>');
                $('#position').append('\n<li>'+localName+'</li>');
            }
        });

    });
})
.success(function() { })
.error(function() { })
.complete(function() {
    var slider = 
      Swipe(document.getElementById('map'), {
        auto: 5000,
        continuous: true,
        callback: function(pos) {

          var i = bullets.length;
          while (i--) {
            bullets[i].className = ' ';
          }
          bullets[pos].className = 'on';

        }
      });

    var bullets = document.getElementById('position').getElementsByTagName('li');
});
```

What happens is: when I see the HTML created by the jQuery, is perfect. jQuery is creating the divs inside the slider and the lis inside the list. Perfect. When I run the website, load and starts perfectly, but then, when changes slide, stops on the second slide, and the second slide is blank. Nothing there. Even thought there is content on the HTML.

The most weird part? If I start the Developer Tools (Command + Alt + I on Chrome), right after the website loads, it WORKS PERFECTLY. What kind of bizar behavior is this? :D

Anybody can help me to make this Swipe JS to run?

Comment: It behaves like this in firefox as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you're populating the slider with content via an AJAX request, then you will most likely have to wait until that AJAX request is finished before you build the slider - i.e. in the success callback of your AJAX function.

Comment: This problem I solved using .responseText; at the end of the ajax. And instead of GET, I had to use those things: type: "POST", async: false. It works fine, but only when I'm using a php as json. Now I'm trying to do the same with a real json, and it's nor working. any idea?